# Update an App With Three20

Tags: ios, iphone, three20

I'm making a new version of an app that use Three20. I have made the decision to stop using Three20 and passing to another lib to make a PhotoGallery. I already know that manual deleting of the Three20 lib isn't an easy operation... So i'm making a new Xcode project with the same bundle identifier for the upload. In this way the user that download the update for his app, delete finally all the files and the references of the Three20? Or the file of a linked library aren't overwritten like the others project classes? I must be sure that Three20 will not appear again with some strange errors in future...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you remove Three20 from your current project or create a new project that doesn't use Three20, you end up with the same result. In the end, you will send an update to Apple with no reference to Three20. When a user updates to your new version of the app, the old app will be replaced with the updated version. So no customer with the new app will have any reference to Three20.

I'm not sure why you are creating a new project just to remove Three20. It's easy enough to remove it from your current project. Just reverse the instructions you followed to add it in the first place. Make sure you do a clean build after removing any files. You should also delete and reinstall the app in the Simulator to ensure deleted files are really gone.

Comment: Just one more tip - keep the same target name when you create the new xcode project. if your target name will be different, users updating from the old version will cause the new version not to open.